# asp.net make virtual directory on database entry

Tags: c#, asp.net, virtual-directory

I have a URL **foo.com/page.aspx?id=1** and the ID is equal to a record in the database.

I would like the website to create a virtual directory as **foo.com/1/** and have it display the same thing after the record is created in the database.

How do I create a virtual directory or is there a way to translate it on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the [IIS url rewrite module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite). That way the page request `foo.com/1` is translated to `foo.com/page.aspx?id=1`.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="pages" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^([0-9/]+)" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="page.aspx?id={R:1}"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Then you can just fetch the id with `string id = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();` on `page.aspx` and show the corresponding contents from the database.

Comment: You're welcome. Just make sure to validate `id` before using it.